# At which maximum step size is the method stable for real $\lambda$?

Tags: numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

I have this Runge-Kutta method:

\begin{array}
{c|cccc}
0\\
\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3}\\
\frac{2}{3} &0 &\frac{2}{3} \\
\hline
& \frac{1}{4} &0 &\frac{3}{4}
\end{array}

I have managed to calculate the region of stability, which is:

$$|1+(\lambda h)+\frac{1}{2}(\lambda h)^2 + \frac{1}{6}(\lambda h)^3| \lt 1$$

We know that $Re \lambda < 0$.

Now I have the question: at which maximum step size ($h$) is the method stable for real $\lambda$? I am unsure how to go about this? Thanks for any help.

Comment: It depends on whether $\lambda$ is $>0$, $=0$ or $<0$ .

Comment: To get my region of stability, I used a test equation where lambda is a constant in the complex numbers and Re (lambda) < 0. Does this help?

Comment: You wrote the criterion up there, it is clear for $\lambda = 0$ it is always true and for $\lambda > 0$ it is always false. Are you working only on $\lambda < 0$ ?

Comment: Yes, Re (lambda) < 0. And I'm trying to find what the maximum h is that the method remains stable.

Comment: I made a mistake - my stability region is < 1, not less than or equal to. I've edited it.

Comment: @Mattos, does this help?

Comment: @AhmadBazzi does this help?

Answer (score 1):

The case $λ>0$ is not stable (meaning bounded) in the exact solution, so it makes no sense to ask for the stability of numerical solutions.

For $λ<0$ you have found that $x=λh$ has to satisfy the inequalities
$$
-1 < 1+x+\frac12x^2+\frac16x^3 < 1
$$
which gives two polynomials to solve. The left one has one real root at $x=-2.5127453266183286$, the right polynomial equation has one real root $0$. This means that the stability condition is satisfied for 
$$-2.5127453266183286<λh<0.$$

Comment: Thank you so much! This makes a lot of sense. This might be a silly question but in the final inequality you have, how does that show me the maximum step size that the region is stable for. Doesn't this show me the range of x values? Which is step-size*lambda?

Comment: Yes, the step size depends on $λ$. For larger $λ$ you need a smaller step size.

Answer (score 0):

For a real $\lambda < 0$, you just fix $z = h\lambda$ and rewrite
$$
-1 < 1 + z + \frac12 z^2 + \frac16 z^3 < 1,
$$
you will find that the right inequality is always true, while the left inequality is true for $z > \bar z$ where $\bar z < 0$ (for a value of $\bar z$, look [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F6%20x%5E3%20%2B%201%2F2%20x%5E2%20%2B%20x%20%2B%202%20%3E%200)). Once you have $\bar z$, you can substitute back and get 
$$
\lambda h > \bar z \implies h < \frac{\bar z}{\lambda},
$$
which is your maximum stepsize. For complex $\lambda$ with $\mathrm{Re}(\lambda) < 0$ it is a bit more messy than that.